# PostgreSQL error when using EXTRACT to get a unit

Tags: database, postgresql, extract

I have been trying to extract the month from a specified time stamp:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM '2019-01-02 00:00:00+00');
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique
>   LINE 1: SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM '2019-01-02 00:00:00+00'); ^ HINT:
>   Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add
>   explicit type casts. SQL state: 42725 Character: 8

However when I use the same command specifying the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP variable, the expected result IS returned.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

How can I get the unit from my first attempt to return teh expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string to timestamp:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-01-02 00:00:00+00');
```

A fragment from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html):

> `EXTRACT(field FROM source)`
>
> (...) `source` must be a value expression of type timestamp, time, or
> interval. (Expressions of type date are cast to timestamp and can
> therefore be used as well.)

Comment: Ah I didn't realise I had to explicitly cast. I thought it would be smart enough to interprit the type! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message when trying to run a similar query via a Postgres adapter for C# and LINQ. The compiled query was passing `DateTime` parameters into clauses like `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ($1))`, even though my LINQ query was written with the `dateTime.Month` integer property (e.g. `dbRecord.created_date.month == myPOCO.created.Month`).

I was able to bypass the issue by pulling `myPOCO.created.Month` out to a separate `int` variable, which allowed the SQL engine to infer an integer parameter instead of a datetime and build a correct (and faster) statement without the calls to `EXTRACT` and `myPOCO.created.Month`.